# RegExp - ignore string outside of tags

Tags: java, regex, string, extract

I need Java RegExp that could match everything except text between tags \begin{name} and \start{name} as shown below (tags can be nested):

```
\start{A}
  im inside
\end{A}

im outside

\start{B}
  \start{B1}
    im inside
  \end{B1}
  im inside
\end{B}

im outside
```

In this case, the expression should ignore all 'im outside' parts.
Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a job for regular expressions.  It requires tracking start tags and their matching end tags... is it guaranteed that the tags will always match up correctly, and if not what do you want to do?  Also, do the tags occur by themselves on a line?

Comment: Can nested tags have the same name?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I have to parse a file in which the names of nested tags may be different

Comment: @JimGarrison As I mentioned I have to parse a file but I can assume that tags are correctly matched up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like :

```
"\\\\start\{([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\}(.*?)\\\\end\{$1\}"
```

with the DOTALL flag to make sure you get newlines.
The inside is group 2.

This can't actually be completed using regular expressions. (You need to recursively dive inside the overall rule when you match a start tag, not possible in regular expressions). The weakness coymes the outer tag also appears inside it, the first end tag will match.

For this you could match the tag with :

```
"\\\\start\{([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\}"
```

And retrieve the tag name as group 1. And start storing which tags you're currently inside in a list. Then match ends tags as

```
"\\\\end\{([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\}"
```

And collect everything between matching tags, while also making sure tags match up.

if tag names are wider than standard identifier names you can change `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*` accordingly.

if you are parsing a file you'll want this approach